# Execute Action when save button is pressed

Tags: xml, orbeon, xforms, xbl

I have an Orbeon form, part of the requirements is that a web service is called when the form is saved.

I've been trying to set this up in Form Builder but cannot seem to find out where the changes need to be done. It's important that this is done within Form Builder as semi-technical people will need to understand the process.

I'm not sure if I need to use custom buttons, or whether I can simply attach an action to the "save" button click.

Answer (score 2):

This would need to be done within the [process](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes) that runs when the *save* button is pressed.

Processes give you a lot of flexibility to configure what happens when buttons at the bottom of the the form are pressed. However, at least as of Orbeon Forms 4.9, processes can't be configured through Form Builder or a web UI, and you need to to edit properties, in your `properties-local.xml`, to do this.